# Is there even a closed-form formula for the number of associative operations on an $n$-element set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, semigroups

I have read many questions that ask for a closed-form formula for the function $f$ that takes a natural number $n$ and outputs the number of associative operations on an $n$-element set. So far, we only know upper and lower bounds for $f$. I suspect now that there is in fact no closed-form formula. So, my question is, has it been proven that there is no closed-form formula? Of course, to answer this question, we need to know a rigorous definition of a closed-form formula for a function. Has any paper or text rigorously defined closed-form formula, and proven that there is no closed-form formula?

Comment: If we don't know the function at all, just bounds, how can we find a formula?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression Borwein i.a.: Closed forms. What they are and  why we care